# Python: removing specific lines from an object

Tags: python

I have a bit of a weird question here.

I am using iperf to test performance between a device and a server. I get the results of this test over SSH, which I then want to parse into values using a parser that has already been made. However, there are several lines at the top of the results (which I read into an object of lines) that I don't want to go into the parser. I know exactly how many lines I need to remove from the top each time though. Is there any way to drop specific entries out of a list? Something like this in psuedo-python

```
print list
["line1","line2","line3","line4"]
list = list.drop([0 - 1])
print list
["line3","line4"]
```

If anyone knows anything I could use I would really appreciate you helping me out. The only thing I can think of is writing a loop to iterate through and make a new list only putting in what I need. Anyway, thanlks!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices:

```
l = ["line1","line2","line3","line4"]
print l[2:] # print from 2nd element (including) onwards 
["line3","line4"]
```

Slices syntax is `[from(included):to(excluded):step]`. Each part is optional. So you can write `[:]` to get the whole list (or any iterable for that matter -- `string` and `tuple` as an example from the built-ins). You can also use negative indexes, so `[:-2]` means from beginning to the second last element. You can also step backwards, `[::-1]` means get all, but in reversed order.

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name. It overrides the built-in list class.

Comment: Don't worry, it was for example only. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [slice](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html) operator is for:

```
>>> before = [1,2,3,4]
>>> after = before[2:]
>>> print after
[3, 4]
```

In this instance, `before[2:]` says 'give me the elements of the list `before`, starting at element 2 and all the way until the end.'

(also -- don't use reserved words like `list` or `dict` as variable names -- doing that can lead to confusing bugs)

Comment: Thanks, list was for example only

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for that:

```
>>> l = ["line1","line2","line3","line4"] # don't use "list" as variable name, it's a built-in.
>>> print l[2:] # to discard items up to some point, specify a starting index and no stop point.
['line3', 'line4']
>>> print l[:1] + l[3:] # to drop items "in the middle", join two slices.
['line1', 'line4']
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use a basic list slice? something like:

```
list = list[3:] #everything from the 3 position to the end
```

Answer (score 1):

You want del for that

```
del list[:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "del" statment to remove specific entries :

```
del(list[0]) # remove entry 0
del(list[0:2]) # remove entries 0 and 1
```